# Is there a software capable of creating native mobile apps with JavaScript, HTML and CSS only?

Tags: javascript

There is a ton of software, so diverse and sophisticated that almost capable of making coffee themselves. We have Electron.JS which builds cross platform desktop apps with JavaScript only. But has there been a software around which does the same with creation of mobile
native apps with web technologies like JavaScript, HTML, and CSS (apart from React Native which
imposes own restrictions and syntax)? I still cannot find one that would be a lightweight compilator, a converter, whose existence 
is logical and of great demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the only option I could find is the creation of a hybrid app with the help of Apache Cordova shell, which is free, cross-platform, and is based on HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript technologies. To get away from attaching necessary modules througth cmd console, we can simply download Visual Studio Community edition of 2017 or higher versions, including under installation a module called 'Develompment with JavaScript". Hybrid apps account for 6% of all apps in public app stores. Another revolutionary way is a newly introduced option by Google allowing to publish Progressive Web Applications (PWA) onto Google Play Store.